# Helmert Transformations

Tags: regression, correlation

Let $Y_f, Y_1,..., Y_n$ denote measurements taken from a father and his n sons. It is assumed that $Y_f, Y_1,...,Y_n$ have equal variance with father-son correlation $ρ_f$ and equal correlation $ρ_S$ between sons. Transform $Y_f, Y_1,..., Y_n$ linearly to $Z_0, Z_1,..., Z_n$ to remove the correlations.

The hint is to let $Z_0=Y_f+c(Y_1+...+Y_n)$ where c is a suitably chosen constant.

Here is what I have tried. 
I let $Z_0, Z_1,..., Z_n$ be the Helmert transformations of $Y_f, Y_1,..., Y_n$ where $Z_j=H_jY$  for j=1,2,...,n and thus, 
[image]

where $Y = Y_1,..., Y_n$

I am stuck until this step and i don't have a clue on how to find the constant c to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: math.stackexchange.com/questions/551299/helmert-transformation –

Comment: Hi @wolfies. Duplicates are allowed across sites; you should use your link as an answer. See [this meta post](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/do-duplicates-count-across-se-sites/1724#1724)

Comment: Hi @PeterFlom Well ... it is a cross-posting of the exact same question, by the same author, to multiple SE sites. My understanding was that that is discouraged.

Comment: Oh. Hmm. I did not notice that it was same author. Not sure what to do here. You could ask on meta.

Comment: yup, done deleting the other one.. So, any guesses for the solution and not if there's any duplicates? Thanks for being observant though.